# How to implement multi TCP client / single TCP server in Android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am new to `JAVA/Android TCP connection`. I try to implement a TCP Server like the following code.

```
private class TCPServerThread implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        ClientAddress = socket.getInetAddress();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can send message to the client when I get the `socket` by `socket = serverSocket.accept();`

**-----------------------------Question-----------------------------**

**Do I need to set different port for client ?**
**But How to get the multiple `socket` from the multiple client ?**

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to set different port for client

No.

> But How to get the multiple socket from the multiple client?

Your code already does that.

Comment: Excuse me , but it only has one parameter for `socket` in my code. If there has two client connect to Server. How do I get two `socket` ?

Comment: You have to keep receiving on the same port , you will receive multiple packets from different clients, you may need to make an identification method inside the packet received. @Martin